# Error in R: roundoff error is detected in the extrapolation table

Tags: r, integrate

I'm trying to calculate consumer surplus with integrate function in R.

```
PID = 2040;
integrand <- function(x) {320000*x^(-0.1)} 
integrate(integrand, lower = PID, upper = Inf,  
          rel.tol=.Machine$double.eps^.05 )$value
```

Then an error shows "roundoff error is detected in the extrapolation table".
If I change the exponent to -1, then no error shows and it emits a value.
How can I fix the error with keeping the exponent value -0.1?

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Not a direct answer, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384330/integrate-function-returning-roundoff-error-after-working-previously) suggests that using the cubature package gives you more chance of success.

Comment: Before you integrate this, you need to be sure that the integral converges. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
PID = 2040;
integrand <- function(x) {320000*x^(-0.1)} 
integrate(integrand, lower = PID, upper = .Machine$double.xmax, rel.tol=.Machine$double.eps^.05 )$value
```